# Processor ID Python 3

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, processor

I want to know my processor ID with Python 3.2. So, google said I should use WMI, but it's only for 2.* version. Are there other ways to solve this problem?

My OS is Windows.

Comment: WMI states it will work with 3.2

Comment: Is this the module you're using: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html ? If so it claims to supports Python 3 as @corn3lius says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a native module such as [pycpuid](http://www.bramz.net/projects-code/pycpuid/) or [cpuidpy](http://code.google.com/p/cpuidpy/).

Alternatively, use the [Python WMI module](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html), which supports Python 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.2, Windows 7:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER']
'x86 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel'
```